# How to create xml scala code format schema for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: xml, scala, intellij-idea

intellij-java-google-style.xml is nice way to format Java code for intelliJ IDEA, it has all goodies from google but also allows you to customize it for some options, for example, change to Tab rather than space for indentation. The XML format solution makes me also want to created an XML code format schema for Scala code. However, I haven't found any solutions yet.

Background: We need a XML code schema for the whole team for the Scala based project, just like what intelliJ-java-google-style.xml provided by google, my question is: how can I create or generate such XML schema? At least if I have to write the XML file what is the rules for Scala? or what option should I put it into the XML file, is it same with the google java XML code schema?

for crate, I prefer: is there any tools that I simply put key value pairs and it will parser to the correct XML schema file for IntelliJ IDEA

for generate, I mean, for example, I can import some format plugin tools such as Scalafmt and export the rules as an XML schema so other people can simply use it by importing the schema

Comment: Have you considered .editorconfig? IDE has support for it.

Comment: @Andrey It is not about how did I consider, team want to use XML schema

Comment: Doesn't it work for you to just set the needed options in IDE and share the IDE schema xml config file with the project: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copying-code-style-settings.html ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Due to a clarification by OP, this answer has become obsolete. Unfortunately, the cannot use scalafmt in their project and need an IntelliJ native solution instead.**

I would recommend you to take a look at the **scalafmt** Project.
It is syntax aware a scala code formatter based on scalameta.

It provides an IntelliJ formatter plugin and integrates nicely with sbt, which allows you to test your sources for correct formatting in your CI build.

It has tons of different options which allow you to customize your desired styling rules, which can be stored in a `.scalafmt.conf` file at the base of your project, or if you want special cases for subprojects, nested in subproject folders.

The Project can be found here: https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/
Or on github, here: https://github.com/scalameta/scalafmt

I am sorry if this does not answer your question entirely, but I am afraid that no intellij-native config file is available at the moment.

To get you started, here is the style file that I use for my personal projects:

```
align = more
maxColumn = 120
docstrings = ScalaDoc
align.tokens = [
  {code = "=>",      owner = "Case"},
  {code = ":",       owner = ".*"},
  {code = "=",       owner = ".*"},
  {code = "extends", owner = ".*"},
  {code = "%",       owner = "Term.ApplyInfix"},
  {code = "%%",      owner = "Term.ApplyInfix"}
]
align.openParenDefnSite = false
optIn.configStyleArguments = true
```

Comment: I do use that myself ! but our team don't want :( democracy issues :)

Comment: I am sorry, I did not see the edit to your question in time.

Comment: No problems :) Please don't delete your post, That's an nice answer though